# Read BLE Characteristic Value in Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, rgb-led

I am trying to build a Smart Led project using Arduino Uno, RGB Led, HM-10 BLE module, and Android device.

I am able to connect HM-10 with my android device and read and write characteristic values using Android BlueDroid stack.

But for this project to work I need to check changes in characteristic value in Arduino and process color value and produce output to light up LED.

I thought I could possibly use AT commands (like AT+Name? AT+POWE? AT+CHAR?) parse their result , but I couldn't find any AT command to read characteristic value. **If anyone know such working AT commands for HM-10, please answer?**

Also, I looked into CurieBLE library from Intel for Arduino. I think the library is to work on an Arduino board which has BLE hardware as a built-in feature. If that's not the case, **please help me how can I communicate Arduino and HM-10 using CurieBLE or any other available library?**

Comment: It sounds like you need to either find the manual for whatever firmware is loaded on your HM10, or else get the TI CC254x SDK and programmer so that you can treat the HM10 as a generic CC254x development board and create your own program for it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to communicate Arduino UNO and HM-10. Whenever one writes a characteristic on BLE using Android application, the exact bytes are transmitted to **Tx/Rx channel** to Arduino and can be read using **SoftwareSerial** Arduino library.

CurieBLE library works on Genuino/Arduino 101 board which has Intel Curie Module.

Comment: This doesn't even remotely try to answer "how". It just answers the "what".

Answer (score 0):

I found this site that discusses the HM-10 and they linked to the datasheet which lists all the AT commands. The set/query characteristics AT command is listed as #13 on page 24.

[Datasheet link.](http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/863.15/doc/tutorials/programming/bluetooth/bluetooth40_en.pdf)

["Bluetooth 4.0 with HM-10" tutorial for MIT course "How To Make (almost) Anything"](http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/863.15/doc/tutorials/programming/bluetooth.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is helpful to add some information of where the link directs to in case the link ever gets broken or moved.